# Unsupported Interpolation Type using env variables in Hydra

Tags: python, hydra, omegaconf

What I'm trying to do: use environment variables in a Hydra config.

I worked from the following links: [OmegaConf: Environment variable interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/1.4_branch/usage.html#environment-variable-interpolation) and [Hydra: Job Configuration](https://hydra.cc/docs/configure_hydra/job/#hydrajobenv_copy).

This is my `config.yaml`:

```
hydra:
  job:
    env_copy:
      - EXPNAME
# I also tried hydra:EXPNAME and EXPNAME, 
# which return None
test: ${env:EXPNAME}
```

Then I set the environment variable (Ubuntu) with:

```
export EXPNAME="123"
```

The error I get is

```
omegaconf.errors.UnsupportedInterpolationType: Unsupported interpolation type env
    full_key: test
    object_type=dict
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (env was removed in a long time ago in favor of oc.env).

```
test: ${oc.env:EXPNAME}
```

I don't think the rest is needed if all you need is to access environment variables on your local machine.